# Matching elements of two lists which are almost the same

Tags: python, difflib

Let's suppose I have two lists of strings. I want to reorder the second list by getting the element that most resembles the corresponding element of the first list.

I already do this :

```
import difflib

list1 = ['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc', 'dddd', 'eeee', 'ffff', 'gggg', 'hhhh', 'iiii', 'jjjj']
list2 = ['eeez', 'fffz', 'dddz', 'cccz', 'iiiz', 'jjjz', 'aaaz', 'gggz', 'hhhz', 'bbbz']

len = len(list1)
i = 0
while i < len:
    j = 0
    while j < len:
        if difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, list1[i], list2[j]).ratio() > 0.5:
            eltMove = list2.pop(j)
            list2.insert(i, eltMove)
            break
        j += 1
    i += 1

print(list2)
```

Output :

```
['aaaz', 'bbbz', 'cccz', 'dddz', 'eeez', 'fffz', 'gggz', 'hhhz', 'iiiz', 'jjjz']
```

But it doesn't work in some cases where there is an element in list2 that match a bit with an element in list1, which break the loop and skip next elements even if they can match better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while i  < len:
    j = 0
    new_l = []
    while j < len:
        new_l.append(difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, list1[i], list2[j]).ratio())
        j += 1
    ind = new_l.index(max(new_l))
    eltMove = list2.pop(ind)
    list2.insert(i, eltMove)
    i += 1
```

It stores the ratios and then calculates the max, finds out the index of the max value and then pops/inserts.

Hope this is what you needed

```
for i, a in enumerate(list1):
    new_l = [difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio() for b in list2]
    ind = new_l.index(max(new_l))
    eltMove = list2.pop(ind)
    list2.insert(i, eltMove)
```

Shortened out the code

Considering @Jose Raul Barreras's reply, the appropriate modification of the above would be:

```
tmp = []
for i, a in enumerate(list1):
    new_l = [difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio() for b in list2]
    ind = new_l.index(max(new_l))
    eltMove = list2.pop(ind)
    tmp.append(eltMove)

>>> tmp
['aaaz', 'bbbz', 'cccz', 'dddz', 'eeez', 'fffz', 'gggz', 'hhhz', 'iiiz', 'jjjz', 
 'aaaz', 'bbbz', 'cccz', 'dddz', 'eeez', 'fffz', 'gggz', 'hhhz', 'iiiz', 'jjjz']
```

Comment: Thank you ! This is exactly what I want :)

Comment: This solution fails with this data: `list1 = ['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc', 'dddd', 'eeee', 'ffff', 'gggg', 'hhhh', 'iiii', 'jjjj']*2
list2 = ['eeez', 'fffz', 'dddz', 'cccz', 'iiiz', 'jjjz', 'aaaz', 'gggz', 'hhhz', 'bbbz']*2`

Comment: Thanks @JoseRaulBarreras fixed

Comment: @M.Klugerford, I'm trying figure out why your code is  slower than mine. Almost twice! Could be when you look for max? Could be done faster?

Comment: It's probably the `pop()`. Try replacing that line with `del list2[ind]` and move the `tmp.append()` above the `del` line. I ran both methods with the `del` instead of `pop` and I got the same speed on both

Answer (score 1):

My two cents. And yes, the solution could be more pythonic...

```
import difflib

def closest_list(list1, list2):
    tmp_list = list2
    res = []
    for elem1 in list1:
        best_value = 0
        best = None
        position = None
        for i, elem2 in enumerate(list2):
            current_value = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, elem1, elem2).ratio()
            if  (current_value > best_value) and (elem2 in tmp_list):
                best_value = current_value
                best = elem2
                position = i
        del tmp_list[position]
        res.append(best)
    return res

a = ['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc', 'dddd', 'eeee', 'ffff', 'gggg', 'hhhh', 'iiii', 'jjjj']*2
b = ['eeez', 'fffz', 'dddz', 'cccz', 'iiiz', 'jjjz', 'aaaz', 'gggz', 'hhhz', 'bbbz']*2
print(closest_list(a,b))
```

**Output:**

> ['aaaz', 'bbbz', 'cccz', 'dddz', 'eeez', 'fffz', 'gggz', 'hhhz',
>   'iiiz', 'jjjz', 'aaaz', 'bbbz', 'cccz', 'dddz', 'eeez', 'fffz',
>   'gggz', 'hhhz', 'iiiz', 'jjjz']

The solution given by @M. Klugerford fails with this data.